# JNI fails to recognize native method

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I created .h file automaticly with javah. And created .c file acordingly. But still eclipse gives me that it **cannot find native methods** and something like this

```
Native method not found: com.iiordanov.bVNC.NativeCalls.getPortAndPassword:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/Str
```

java file:

```
package com.iiordanov.bVNC;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NativeCalls {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("start-spice-xml");
    }
   public native static  String[] getPortAndPassword(String server, String name)  throws IOException;
}
```

.h file (From extern C it writes syntax error)

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls */

#ifndef _Included_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls
#define _Included_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls
 * Method:    getPortAndPassword
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

.c file (tried with and without extern "C" before JNIEXPORT)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls.h>

char *create_request(char *vm_name);

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass myClass, jstring nameString, jstring serverString)
...
```

Looked thrue several posts - they all say that i should add extern C - but it doesn'y help((

LogCat

```
03-14 19:32:09.809: E/AndroidRuntime(1157): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.iiordanov.bVNC.NativeCalls.getPortAndPassword:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
```

Android.mk file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := start-spice-xml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-c-files-under,libxml2)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here i just added mine file start-spice.c and generated header for NativeCalls.java to libxml2 .c's and .h's.

Comment: Which is it, a syntax error or a runtime inability to find the function?  What logcat message is generated as a result of the loadLibrary call?  What is your library's .so file actually called?

Comment: @ChrisStratton added everything as you said here

Comment: You don't have to add 'extern "C"' in the.c file as long as you are including the .h file. The compiler gets it from there. It all looks OK. Are you sure that .c file is included in the compilation and link? The usual cause of these errors is changing the Java file without regenerating the .h file and modifying the .c file to still agree, as changing the method name or class name or package name changes the native method name.

Comment: @EJP I did with both extern C and without (and i know i didn't need to). And i have looked thrue different cases with that mistake( Well as you can see everything seems to be coreect with the method (Java_Pachage_Method) and as far as i know Android mk automaticly links .h files if you mention .c files if they are in the same folder((( So i really have no clue what i did wrong(((

Comment: @EJP maybe it is wrong to choose name javah generate for my .h? I mean there are lots of these _ in there com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls.h and the linker from Android.mk is not linking because of that? (Well i think it is unlikely but it can be)

Comment: @EJP Can the problem be with compiler? As i use C code while it install stdc++?

Comment: All C compilers 'link' .h files with .c files when the .c file includes the .h file, as here. I don't know what 'choose name javah generate for my .h' means. My question was whether you're sure that the .c file got compiled and linked. You haven't answered it.

Comment: Is your Android.mk complete here? I don't see you including the header there.

Comment: @EJP I am sure that is is linked because it is in one folder. And by linking I mean android.mk linkes when i set c source files.

Comment: @eozgonul It is - because Android ndk automaticly links .h files if they are in the same folder as .c files.

Comment: Are you sure that LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-c-files-under,libxml2) works correctly? I think your source file is not compiled into the library.

Comment: @Morckovka The statement you keep making that 'Android automatically links .h files' is completely meaningless. .h files are compiled, not linked, and this happens as part of compiling .c files that include them, not because of anything magical that Android does. It's a normal function of any C compiler. They don't produce object code of their own, so there is nothing to link. You don't seem to understand the process you're describing, whatever it is. The question remains whether the .c file got linked, and you still haven't answered it. On the current evidence the answer appears to be 'no'.